# libgdx setScreen() on a screen twice and it does not work second time

Tags: java, libgdx, game-engine

This is the class that I am initializing via my desktop and android main class. I am actually passing this current instance of Game to GameScreen objects so that I can use its setScreen method to change screens.

```
public class childGame extends Game {
     @Override
     public void create() { 
         setScreen(new AScreen(this));

     }
}
```

And at somepoint at `AScreen` I am changing Screen to another Screen say `BScreen` when the button is pressed, I am also using the same trick that I have previously here, and it works fine. but when from `BScreen` I change setScreen to `AScreen`, it goes there shows everything correctly but none of the buttons do work.

Comment: Can u please share ur AScreen ans BScreen for a better understanding of your question

Answer (score 0):

disposing the screen would solve thiss,

call dispose method when you are switching screens

```
game.setScreen(new PlayScreen(game));    
dispose();
```